# Memory Leak in video tag HTML5 firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video, webrtc

I have been using RTCMultiConnection for screen sharing which works perfectly in Chrome but when the Video is streamed in firefox, it starts to show lag, and eventually the application consumes a lot of memory. Can anybody help me in solving this problem? How is it possible to clear the memory?

Comment: I've just discovered the same problem while developing an Parallax SPA. every time it a video play fires, the memory grows and grows until firefox crashes.

Comment: @r3wt Got any solution for it?